# iOS 13 - Segue modally to a new storyboard nv/vc in full screen programmatically

Tags: xcode, ios13, swift5

With the new iOS 13 upgrade, my app now doesn't display my modally segues in full screen. How do I resolve this issue?

```
    let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Admin", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AdminNav") as UIViewController
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `modalPresentationStyle` to `.fullScreen`:

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Admin", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AdminNav")
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```